# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}1-\cos{\frac{\pi}{n}}$ and little $o$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, asymptotics

I want to study the convergence or divergence of $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}1-\cos{\frac{\pi}{n}}.$$

First of all it is a positive terms series since $\cos{\frac{\pi}{n}}\leq 1$. I want so to apply the asymptote criterion test and I observe that:
$$1-\cos{\frac{\pi}{n}}=1-1+\frac{\pi^2}{2n^2}+o(\frac{\pi^3}{n^3})=\frac{\pi^2}{2n^2}+o(\frac{\pi^3}{n^3})\sim \frac{\pi^2}{2n^2}.$$
So since $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\pi^2}{2n^2}$ is convergent the original series converges.

**Questions:**

1. Do you think my work is correct?
2. when I have $o(x^3)+o(x^2)$ this is equal to $o(x^2)$ for $x\to 0$, in essence I am taking the little o of the term that goes to $0$ more slowly and so all terms of kind $x^k$ with $k>2$ are collected in $o(x^2)$.
   Now I think $o(1/n^2)+o(1/n^3)=o(1/n^2)$ since $1/n^2$ goes to $0$ more slowly than $1/n^3$ as $n\to\infty$. So $\frac{\pi^2}{2n^2}$ will not be collected in $o(\frac{\pi^3}{n^3})$, right? But I have to collect in  $o(\frac{\pi^3}{n^3})$ only terms of kind  $\frac{\pi^3}{n^k}$ with $k>3$.

Comment: I would prefer big $O$ though. $\cos(\pi/n) = 1 + O(1/n^2)$. That's it.

Comment: @VIVID thanks for the suggestion but I am used to use little $o$, is right my work?

Comment: $0 \leq 1-\cos t \leq \frac {t^{2}} 2$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thanks it is cleverer than my way!

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy this equality holds only definitely?

Comment: The inequality is true for all real numbers $t$. The minimum value of $\frac {t^{2}} 2 -(1-\cos t)$ over  the entire real line is $0$ (attined at $t=0$ and you can check this easily by differentiation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your attempt is correct. But I would rather justify it by the fact that$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}=\frac12,$$from which it follows that$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1-\cos\left(\frac\pi n\right)}{\left(\frac\pi n\right)^2}=\frac12.$$And now, just as you did, I would use the convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\pi^2}{n^2}$.

Comment: Ok thanks as matter of fact the taylor expansion at the first order is nothing but that a notable limit! What's about my second question? Is it right what I have written down?

Comment: Well, I began my answer with “Your attempt is correct”.

Comment: Ah ok sorry I thought this was referred only to the work on series and not also to the remark on little o!

Answer (score 1):

$a_n:=\dfrac{(1-\cos (\pi/n)) (1+\cos(\pi/n))}{1+\cos (\pi/n)}$

$a_n=\dfrac{\sin^2(\pi/n)}{1+\cos(\pi/n)}$;

We have

$\sin (\pi/n) < (\pi/n) $, and $0<\cos (\pi/n) <1$ for large n.

$a_n<\dfrac{(\pi/n)^2}{1}=\dfrac{(\pi)^2}{n^2}.$

Comparison test.